# Negative arguments to head / tail

Tags: shell-script, osx, tail, options, head

Variants of this question have certainly been asked several times in different places, but I am trying to remove the last `M` lines from a file without luck.

The [second most voted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12349094/283296) in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4881930/bash-remove-the-last-line-from-a-file) recommends doing the following to get rid of the last line in a file:

```
head -n -1 foo.txt > temp.txt
```

However, when I try that in OSX & Zsh, I get:

```
head: illegal line count -- -1
```

Why is that? How can I remove the `M` **last** lines **and** the **first** `N` lines of a given file?

Comment: See [POSIX head and tail not feature equivalent](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/75935/22565)

Comment: What is the output of `head --version`? What system are you using?

Comment: @jofel `head --version` returns an error actually.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You can remove the first 12 lines with:

```
tail -n +13
```

(That means print from the 13<sup>th</sup> line.)

Some implementations of `head` like GNU `head` support:

```
head -n -12
```

but that's not standard.

```
tail -r file | tail -n +13 | tail -r
```

would work on those systems that have `tail -r` (see also GNU `tac`) but is sub-optimal.

Where `n` is 1:

```
sed '$d' file
```

You can also do:

```
sed '$d' file | sed '$d'
```

to remove 2 lines, but that's not optimal.

You can do:

```
sed -ne :1  -e 'N;1,12b1' -e 'P;D'
```

But beware that won't work with large values of *n* with some `sed` implementations.

With `awk`:

```
awk -v n=12 'NR>n{print line[NR%n]};{line[NR%n]=$0}'
```

To remove `m` lines from the beginning and `n` from the end:

```
awk -v m=6 -v n=12 'NR<=m{next};NR>n+m{print line[NR%n]};{line[NR%n]=$0}'
```

Comment: `sed 'x;1d;$d'` might be used to get the last two lines as well. And w/ a couple of `N`'s after `1d` might be used to get a little more than that, though at that point it offers no advantage over the `N;P;D` loop you already recommend.

Comment: Thank you -- The last command is extremely helpful. A summer small caveat: it doesn't work when `m` or `n` are `0`. Otherwise it would be perfect.

Comment: @AmelioVazquez-Reina, it should work for `m` == 0. For `n` == 0, just use `tail`, using `awk` for that would be overkill (though that should just be `awk -v m=12 'NR > m'`)

Comment: it's kinda bizarre that tail supports `+13` but head does not support `-13`. Lack of symmetry, I'd say. Any hope that head would be updated ?

Comment: @CiprianTomoiagă, some do like I said. You could request that feature be added to the maintainer of the `head` implementation you're using. We can request POSIX specify it, which as long as a majority of implementations already implement it, would likely be accepted.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the following way to remove first N lines and last M lines.

With `N=5`, `M=7` and file `test.txt`:

```
sed -n -e "6,$(($(wc -l < test.txt) - 7))p" test.txt
```

The command prints all lines from N+1 to LastLine-M.

Another option is to use python:

```
python -c 'import sys;print "".join(sys.stdin.readlines()[5:-7]),' < test.txt
```

python3:

```
python -c 'import sys;print("".join(sys.stdin.readlines()[5:-7]))' < test.txt
```

To override the existing file:

```
python -c 'import sys;print("".join(sys.stdin.readlines()[5:-7]))' < test.txt > temp.txt && mv temp.txt test.txt
```

Answer (score 2):

You can remove the last `M` (here M=100) lines from a file with:

```
head -$(($(wc -l < foo.txt) - 100)) foo.txt > temp.txt
```